# Having issues with NVL in select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to display a vendor address which is composed of three concatenated fields such as address, state, zip. My only issue is that one of the vendors has a null value for his address so it reads NULL STATE ZIP.

I tried:

```
SELECT vendor_name, NVL(vendor_address1, ' ') || ' ' || vendor_state || ' ' || VENDOR_ZIP_CODE AS "Complete Address"
from ap.vendors;
```

As well as

```
SELECT vendor_name, NVL(to_char(vendor_address1), ' ') || ' ' || vendor_state || ' ' || VENDOR_ZIP_CODE AS "Complete Address"
from ap.vendors;
```

But the null is always displayed as NULL.

Not sure what my options are at this point.

Comment: Is the datatype of vendor_address1 type of string? And just to be sure there is a vendor_name for the record you say had no address?

Comment: are you sure it is null not string `NULL` ?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured out the issue, or at least I think I did. Null wasn't a type but a string, so when I used the replace function it worked.

Comment: A word of advice. Never store `NULL` as string 'NULL'. You can read [this](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/313819/how-does-a-surname-of-null-cause-problems-in-many-databases) for the issues this might cause.